# Where do phpinfo date settings come from?

Tags: php, datetime

When I do type `php -i` I get the following:

```
date

date/time support => enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 0.system
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => America/New_York
```

Where do these settings come from and do they impact behavior of datetime functions?

For instance, despite what is said in [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) `date_default_timezone_get` returns to me `America/New_York` without any warnings and ignoring the fact that my `date.timezone => no value` and `date_default_timezone_set` doesn't apply. Is it affected by `Default timezone => America/New_York`?

[The comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php#113202) implies it is Ubuntu-specific behavior. Is it?

**NB.**
I observed the behavior on 2 configurations: `Ubuntu 16.04 + php 7.2.7` and `Debian 8.7 + php 5.6.30`

Comment: Which operating system you are using?

Comment: Added details on that.

Comment: phpinfo should show which ini file(s) are being loaded..

Comment: It comes not from an ini file. I have `date.timezone => no value` in my inis.

Comment: Depending on your operating system and configuration, it is possible that your CLI configuration may use a different INI entry point than your Web server / FPM configuration, so `php -i` and `phpinfo();` may return different configuration.

Comment: The fact is that I know for sure my ini entry point. And `date.timezone` is not set there: `ini_get('date.timezone'); // string(0) ''`. I do not have a call of `date_default_timezone_set` as well. Despite that `date_default_timezone_get(); // America/New_York`

Answer (score -1):

Configuration for PHP comes from a .ini file. There may be more than one version of PHP installed on your machine. Below a screenshot from when I put `<?php phpinfo();exit;` as the entire code in the file.

[image]

This shows the "Loaded Configuration File" for the way I've used the PHP installed, in this case, with Xampp.

Check the same entry in your `phpinfo()` output and find out what the entry is. Then check that file.

In my case I have this (when searching "timezone"):

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
;date.timezone =
```

This part is not used. So, keep looking, there's either a value or a piece of config somewhere. In mine I have this later on:

```
[Date]
date.timezone=Europe/Berlin
```

Further, have a look at the PHP functions to [get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) and [set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) a timezone.

The get function (`date_default_timezone_get()`) gets the timezone like so:

> In order of preference, this function returns the default timezone by:
>
> - Reading the timezone set using the date_default_timezone_set()
>     function (if any)
> - Prior to PHP 5.4.0 only: Reading the TZ environment variable (if non
>     empty)
> - Reading the value of the date.timezone ini option (if set)
> - Prior to PHP 5.4.0 only: Querying the host operating system (if
>     supported and allowed by the OS). This uses an algorithm that has to
>     guess the timezone. This is by no means going to work correctly for
>     every situation. A warning is shown when this stage is reached. Do not
>     rely on it to be guessed correctly, and set date.timezone to the
>     correct timezone instead.
>
> If none of the above succeed, date_default_timezone_get() will return
>   a default timezone of UTC.

Comment: Sorry, I think you've misread my post. I pointed out that the ini `date.timezone` setting is undefined in my case, `date_default_timezone_set` is not called and therefore `date_default_timezone_get` doesn't behave according to the doc specification.

Comment: I thought I understood correctly and thought to put the default behavior down as well. If the system your on does not have a timezone set, then it should return UTC, if the system has a timezone, then that should be returned. Next is config and most local is in the code itself. If all of that is not going according to spec, then I suggest you report a bug with PHP, instructions [start here](https://bugs.php.net/).